# The same service broker service names on different databases on the same instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I created server1<-->server2 communication via service broker. I defined the routes on both servers and it works well. When I am defined the route, I used following code:

```
CREATE ROUTE [SB_Cms_TimesheetRoute]
WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//DB1/DB2/UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService',
ADDRESS = 'tcp://$(DB1_SERVER):4022';
```

Everything works - no complains. The only thing I can not understand is that I can create services with the SAME name on DIFFERENT databases on $(DB1_SERVER) instance. How will service broker understand what instance to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating multiple services under the same name is understood by Service Broker as a scale out scenario. The CREATE ROUTE has an optional `BROKER_INSTANCE` parameter which you omitted, that is crucial in dealing with multiple instances of the same service. The `broker_instance` must match the `service_broker_guid` value from the destination [sys.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx).

Lets say you created two services, both named `'//UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService'` (you should never put `DB1` or `DB2` in the service name). One service is in DB1, which has service_broker_guid value `8597e044-6057-423f-978c-096b0c4212b7` and the other one is in DB2 which has service_broker_guid values `29acd670-77bb-47da-baf9-fc74b714c8dd`. The you would create two routes, one for each:

```
CREATE ROUTE [SB_Cms_TimesheetRoute_DB1]
WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService',
BROKER_INSTANCE = '8597e044-6057-423f-978c-096b0c4212b7',
ADDRESS = 'tcp://$(DB1_SERVER):4022';

CREATE ROUTE [SB_Cms_TimesheetRoute_DB2]
WITH SERVICE_NAME = '//UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService',
BROKER_INSTANCE = '29acd670-77bb-47da-baf9-fc74b714c8dd',
ADDRESS = 'tcp://$(DB2_SERVER):4022';
```

Now whener you begin a new dialog targeting the `//UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService` service, the Service Broker will route your first message two either one of the two possible destinations. All subsequent messages *sent on the same dialog* will deterministically  choose the same destination. You can dynamically add more instances of the service later, just declare a corresponding route with a correct `BROKER_INSTANCE` value.

You can also target the service instance you want explicitly by specifying the desired broker instance in the BEGIN DIALOG statement:

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @h 
FROM ...
TO '//UpdatedJobAssignments_TargetService', '29acd670-77bb-47da-baf9-fc74b714c8dd'
ON CONTRACT ...
WITH ...;
```

This syntax will make the dialog to deterministically target the service in DB2.
This is needed, for instance, where you know that the state needed to process your dialog is in DB2.